# Convert duplicate filtered json output back to json object?

Tags: python, json, filter, duplicates

I am trying to remove all duplicate entries from a json object.
I have the following json list:

```
[ 
  { 
    "hello": "abc",
    "world": "bla"
  },
  {
    "hello": "def",
    "world": "blubb"
  },
  {
    "hello": "ghe",
    "world": "bla"
  },
  {
    "hello": "jkl",
    "world": "bla"
  }
]
```

I want to remove all duplicates of the key `world`, keeping only the first occurrence of duplicates.
The result should then be:

```
[ 
  { 
    "hello": "abc",
    "world": "bla"
  },
  {
    "hello": "def",
    "world": "blubb"
  }
]
```

I know I can achieve this like so:

`unique = {each['world']: each for each in json_data}.values()`

But I can't seem to get back a valid json object - only `dict_values`.
How can I get back a valid json object that has the duplicates removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the dict values back to json with [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) if you need that:

```
import json
json.dumps(list(unique))
```